# Grails: validate file uploads

Tags: java, validation, forms, grails, file-upload

My Grails app has an upload form like the following:

```
<g:uploadForm action="save" >
    <input type="file" name="csvfile" />
    <!-- some other inputs ... -->
    <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Save" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

I don't want to store the file contents in the domain object, but want to transfer them directly to file with the `transferTo` method. How can I perform validation in this case (perhaps with a command object)?

Answer (score 3):

When you upload a file, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
def myAction = {
    def file = request.get('csvfile')
    file.transferTo(new File('/path/to/local/file'))
}
```

I'm not understanding the connection between your question and how the inputs in your form would map to a domain object. If you don't want the file contents on your domain, you shouldn't have a domain field defined for them.

If you can provide us with your domain we can better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The domain class contains only the filename, but that doesn't matter in my example. I want to know how I can ensure that the user sends the required files with the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit brute-force, but just use the sample code provided by @Rob Hruska and look for the files in the action. It's not particularly elegant, but it's functional and simple, and doesn't put files into your domain object.